# Python row.get(regex)

Tags: python, regex

I have been searching for this for a few hours now and I can't seem to find anything about it.

I am parsing a .csv file and I need to pull email addresses out of it. The headers indicate whether it is an email or not, but it is possible for the files to have different formats and I want to handle this with a regex, but I don't know how to do this.

A part of my code is below:

```
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("contacts.csv"))
for row in input_file:
if row.get('E-mail 1 - Value'):
    print row.get('E-mail 1 - Value')
elif row.get('E-mail 2 - Value'):
    print row.get('E-mail 2 - Value')
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("contacts.csv"))
for row in input_file:
if row.get('E-mail*'):
    print row.get('E-mail*')
```

Where it will grab anything that has a header starting with email, but I can't seem to figure out how. I tried to use re.search, but it wasn't what I needed since I don't know how to give it the input string. Thanks in advance for any help!

William

Comment: Are you sure row.get is valid ? Also, can you post an example of the csv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that prints all the contents of the columns that start with "E-mail" for every row:

```
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("contacts.csv"))
for row in input_file:
    for column in row.keys():
        if column.startswith("E-mail"):
           print row[column]
```